# Let $X$ be a compact metric space. If $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is lower semi-continuous, then $f$ is bounded from below and attains its infimum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, compactness, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. If $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is lower semi-continuous, then $f$ is bounded from below and attains its infimum. I want to prove this.

This is my proof:

Since $X$ is compact then it follows that $f(X)$ is compact therefore it is closed and bounded (because $f(K)$ is in $\mathbb{R}$) and therefore $f$ has an infimum, $m = \inf f(x)$.
Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$. Since $X$ is compact by equivalence it is sequentially compact. There is a sub-sequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow m \in\mathbb{R}$ since it is closed. Then by the lower semi-continuity of $f$ we have that
$$m = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf(x_n) =   \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf(x_{n_k})\geq f(x) \geq m. $$ Thus $$m\geq f(x) \geq m.$$
Hence $m = f(x)$. Therefore $f$ attains its minimum and is bounded below.

(I did not assume $X$ was closed and bounded because it is not necessarily a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$).  This also is not homework I am trying to prove the theorems my book left blank to see if I really understand concepts. Any help and comments would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that $f(X)$ is necessarily closed.

Comment: @T.Bongers But $f$ is only lower semi-continuous. E.g., if $X=[0,1]$ and $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x=0$,}\\x+1&\text{if $x\in(0,1],$}\end{cases}$$ then $f(X)=\{0\}\cup(1,2]$, which is not closed.

Comment: You have left out many steps, and produced an $x$ from nowhere in the first formula. I have given a standard line of reasoning below.

Comment: I thought that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is sequentially compact if and only if it is closed and bounded? $f(X)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Actually sorry I missed something in the theorem. It says if $X$ is compact and $f$ continuous then $f(X)$ is compact. That means it has to be both LSC and USC.

Comment: Well, you could show that if $f$ is lsc., then it is continuous if you use the right-order topology on the range, and then use the usual result for continuous functions. But not much point really...

Comment: Thank you for the help and comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $m = \inf f$, there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) \to m$. This is true just by the definition of $\inf$.

Since $x_n \in X$ and $X$ is compact, we have some $\hat{x} \in X$ and some subsequence such that $x_{n_k} \to \hat{x}$. This follows since $X$ is compact, and hence sequentially compact (equivalent in a metric space in any case).

Since $f$ is lsc., we have $\liminf_n f(x_{n_k}) \ge f(\hat{x})$. This is by definition of lsc.

Since $\liminf_n f(x_{n_k}) = \lim_n f(x_{n_k})  = m$, we have $m \ge f(\hat{x})$, and by definition of $m$, we have $m \le f(\hat{x})$, hence $\hat{x}$ is a minimizer.

**Note**: The above proof does not depend on $m$ being finite (the proof shows that $m$ is finite, since $m \ge f(\hat{x})$). However, it is straightforward to show that $m$ is finite directly.

Since $f$ ls lsc., at any $x$, for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $y \in B(x,\delta)$, then $f(y) > f(x)-\epsilon$.

So, choose $\epsilon=1$, then for each $x$ we have some $\delta_x >0$ such that if $y \in B(x,\delta_x)$, then $f(y) > f(x)-1$. The $B(x,\delta_x)$ form an open cover of $X$, hence by compactness, there is a finite subcover $B(x_k,\delta_{x_k})$. Hence $f(x) > \min(f(x_1),...,f(x_n))-1$, from which it follows that $m \ge \min(f(x_1),...,f(x_n))-1$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. I got the impression that you were done with the latest exchange, so this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58824/discussion-on-answer-by-copper-hat-let-x-be-a-compact-metric-space-if-fx-ri) where you can still review it, if the need persists.

Comment: Hello, I read your answer and I have a question. $m$ is defined to be $\liminf_n f(x_{n_k})$, or not? Showing that $m \ge \min(f(x_1),...,f(x_n))-1$ tels us that the function attains its minimum, right?

Comment: No, $m$ is defined to be the $\inf_{x \in X} f(x)$. The above shows that there is some $\hat{x}$ such that $f(\hat{x}) = m$ hence there is a $\min$.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ need not be a metric space. We only require it to be compact.

> At first we prove $\inf_{x\in X}f(x)\not=-\infty $

Suppose by way of contradiction that this is not the case. This means that the family of closed sets $\mathcal{F}=\{f^{-1}(-\infty, \alpha]\:;\: \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ has the property of finite intersection (PFI). That is:

$$\cap_{i=1}^nf^{-1}(-\infty, \alpha_i]=f^{-1}(-\infty,\min_{1\leq i\leq n}\alpha_i]\not=\emptyset$$

Because $X$ is compact, we need $\cap_{\alpha\in \mathbb{R}} f^{-1}(-\infty, \alpha]\not=\emptyset$.  (If it were empty, take an open covering of $X$ using the complement of this infinite interesection, extract a finite subcover and take the complement again to contradict the PFI). $\square$

> Now we prove that $\inf_{x\in X}f(x)$ is attained.

Suppose not. Then $\cup_{j=1}^\infty f^{-1}(\inf_{x\in X}f(x)+1/2^j,\infty )$ is an open covering of $X$ which admits no finite subcover. This is absurd because of $X$ being compact. $\square$